# TypeError: Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance. In order to be iterable,

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to use the API context on react native and I am getting the following error below.

**TypeError: Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance.
In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a Symbol.iterator method.**

This is what my code looks like

```
import React, {createContext, useState, useContext} from 'react';

const PurchasesContext = createContext();

export const PurchasesContextProvider = ({children}) => {
  const [purchases, setPurchases] = useState([]);
  return (
    <PurchasesContext.Provider value={[purchases, setPurchases]}>
      {children}
    </PurchasesContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const usePurchasesContext = () => {
  const [purchases, setPurchases] = useContext(PurchasesContext);

  return {
    purchases,
    setPurchases,
  };
};
```

Then I am using it like so

```
const {purchases, setPurchases} = usePurchasesContext();
```

Does anybody know why this is happening and how can I fix it been trying for hours now?

Comment: Did you wrapp your App.js with your provider ?
Also, in your component where you use it, you should pass the context

`import { PurchasesContextProvider } from '/the/path/to/your/file'
 const { pruchases, setPurchases } = React.useContext(PurchasesContextProvider)`

Comment: nevermind I solved by just doing this ```const PurchasesContext = createContext([[], () => {}]);```

Comment: Ok good for you dude :)

Comment: This error can be caused passing in the value to the provider incorrectly. Check the braces and brackets are correct. See:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/67644741/1271903

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind I solved it by doing the following

```
const PurchasesContext = createContext([[], () => {}]);
```